# Reactive Forms selected option is Object object in formcontrol

Tags: javascript, angular

In my component I have the following member Store :

```
stores : Store[]
```

Store is the following interface:

```
export interface Store{
  store_name: string;
  owner: string;
  display_name?: string;
}
```

I have the following select in my html :

```
  <select [formControlName]="stores" >
    <option value="null" hidden selected>Select</option>
    <ng-container *ngIf="selectedProduct">
        <option *ngFor="let store of stores" [value]="store">
            {{ store.display_name }}
        </option>
      </ng-container>
    </select>
```

This select is connected to the following formControl :

```
 constructor(......) {
    this.fg= new FormGroup({
      ....
      stores: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]), 
      ...
    });
```

why in my onSubmit method I'm getting undefined when I  try to access the fields of the chosen store ? :

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.fg.get("stores").value.store_name); // undefined
     .....
}
```

btw : Using angular 10.

Comment: Use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`?

Comment: @JasonWhite it worked, can u explain why ? I understood the diff by googling, tnx :) The only difference between two is that value is always string, where in ngValue you can pass object

Comment: `[value]` is always a string, if you want to bind an object you need to use `[ngValue]`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was using {{}} for accessing the loop variable, and without [] around ngValue. And was getting [object Object] for value.

incorrect:

```
 <option *ngFor="let center of service.allCenters" ngValue="{{center}}">
          <p> {{center.description}}</p>
        </option>
```

correct:

```
<option *ngFor="let center of service.allCenters" [ngValue]="center">
  <p> {{center.description}}</p>
</option>
```

And notice that I'm using ngValue instead of value.